# Android overlay a view ontop of everything?

Tags: java, android, layout, view

Can you overlay a view on top of everything in android?

In iPhone I would get the new view set its `frame.origin` to (0,0) and its width and height to the width and height of `self.view`. Adding it to `self.view` would then cause it to act as an overlay, covering the content behind (or if it had a transparent background then showing the view behind).

Is there a similar technique in android? I realise that the views are slightly different (there are three types (or more...) relativelayout, linearlayout and framelayout) but is there any way to just overlay a view on top of everything indiscriminately?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Simply use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. The last child view will overlay everything else.

Android supports a pattern which Cocoa Touch SDK doesn't: Layout management.
*Layout* for iPhone means to position everything absolute (besides some strech factors). Layout in android means that children will be placed in relation to eachother.

Example (second EditText will completely cover the first one):

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_view">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

</FrameLayout>
```

`FrameLayout` is some kind of view stack. Made for special cases.

`RelativeLayout` is pretty powerful. You can define rules like *View A has to align parent layout bottom*, *View B has to align A bottom to top*, etc

**Update based on comment**

Usually you set the content with `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` in `onCreate` (it will inflate the layout for you). You can do that manually and call `setContentView(inflatedView)`, there's no difference.

The view itself might be a single view (like `TextView`) or a complex layout hierarchy (nested layouts, since all layouts are views themselves).

After calling `setContentView` your activity knows what its content looks like and you can use `(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view)` to retrieve any view int this hierarchy (General pattern `(ClassOfTheViewWithThisId) findViewById(R.id.declared_id_of_view)`).

Comment: Ah thanks for the example. So I'm guessing in an activity the content view is probably a framelayout? If I use a `layoutinflater` to grab a `relativelayout` from a layout xml file how can I add it to the content view? Is there a way to get a reference to the content view? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, so it explains what the content of an activity is and how to interact with it.

Comment: I'd like to point out that while I prefer `FrameLayout` due to its lightweight nature, it fails to propagate the maximum measured height (aka its own resulting height) to its children in case of `match_parent` height, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780884/1856738). Therefore, when supporting Android 2 and working with `match_parent`, `RelativeLayout` is the only working option; for an example [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/965641/1856738).

Comment: JFYI: At Android 4.4.4 for me it was enough to place an fragment as overlay. Since Android 5.0 some elements like buttons and cardviews where placed on top. With the solution in the answer, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 20):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/Everything"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- other actual layout stuff here EVERYTHING HERE -->

   </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Now any view you add under LinearLayout with **`android:id = "@+id/overlay"`** will appear as overlay with **gravity = right** on Linear Layout with  **`android:id="@+id/Everything"`**

Comment: Wish I'd have seen this at the beginning of the afternoon. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `bringToFront`:

```
    View view=findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
    view.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way is [ViewOverlay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay.html) , You can add any drawable as overlay to any view as its overlay since Android JellyBeanMR2(Api 18).

Add `mMyDrawable` to `mMyView` as its overlay:

```
mMyDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mMyView.getMeasuredWidth(), mMyView.getMeasuredHeight())
mMyView.getOverlay().add(mMyDrawable)
```

Comment: typo: mMyDrawable.setBounds

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But you can access view components from image. For example if there's a button in your view if you click the image, the original view button will be clicked automatically.

Comment: @RanjithSubramaniam Yes, because of it is just overlay-drawable drawn over the view.

Comment: But it won't work in case a view has to be put on top of another as a drawable is  only a graphic

Answer (score 1):

I have just made a solution for it. I made a [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark) for this to do that in a reusable way that's why you don't need to recode in your XML. Here is documentation on how to use it in [Java](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark#by-java) and [Kotlin](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark#by-kotlin). First, initialize it from an activity from where you want to show the overlay-

```
AppWaterMarkBuilder.doConfigure()
                .setAppCompatActivity(MainActivity.this)
                .setWatermarkProperty(R.layout.layout_water_mark)
                .showWatermarkAfterConfig();
```

Then you can hide and show it from anywhere in your app -

```
  /* For hiding the watermark*/
  AppWaterMarkBuilder.hideWatermark() 

  /* For showing the watermark*/
  AppWaterMarkBuilder.showWatermark()
```

Gif preview -

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1):

bringToFront() is super easy for programmatic adjustments, as stated above. I had some trouble getting that to work with button z order because of stateListAnimator. If you end up needing to programmatically adjust view overlays, and those views happen to be buttons, **make sure to set stateListAnimator to null in your xml layout file.** stateListAnimator is android's under-the-hood process to adjust translationZ of buttons when they are clicked, so the button that is clicked ends up visible on top. This is not always what you want... for full Z order control, do this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the awnsers before but this did not work.
Now I jsut used a LinearLayout instead of a TextureView, now it is working without any problem. Hope it helps some others who have the same problem. :)

```
    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view); //this is initialized in the constructor
    openWindowOnButtonClick();

public void openWindowOnButtonClick()
{
    view.setAlpha((float)0.5);
    FloatingActionButton fb = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    final InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getBaseContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // check if the Overlay should be visible. If this value is false, it is not shown -> show it.
            if(view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
            {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
                Log.d("Overlay", "Klick");
            }
            else if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
```

Comment: I think in order to make this a really helpful answer, you should add a bit more. Example code, screenshots, ...