# (Android) How to put a TextView int the Center of the screen (Not in the Layout or Parent View) if I have a Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: android, textview

This is my problem: I have a (horizontally) very large `View` and, of course, I have a scroll to move it side by side. I want to put a `TextView` in middle, but I want it so, that when I scroll horizontally and the `View` moves this `TextView` stays in the center of the screen.

If I use `android:gravity="center"` or something like this, as the view is very large, I will NOT see the TextView in the center unless I am in the center of the view (Not in the beginning, and not in the end) but I need that the `TextView` is in the center during the whole scrolling.

Comment: Although you said this is a large lib, you should create a smaller variant of your problem, so people could check it easier (which would mean you might get an answer more quicker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can achieve that by positioning the element in the middle by setting its x-origin (with left-padding or left-margin?) to `(scrollview.width/2 - textview.width/2)`, then add the **scrollview.offset.x** whenever the scrollview scrolls (add a listener to get this) so it maintains still at the relative center.

However the simplest thing may be to place a FrameLayout which contains the ScrollView and above it the TextView, which you could then center with the gravity property.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your content is all inside a ScrollView.  You will need your TextView to be outside of this scroll view: you can then use the technique described in "[Android overlay a view ontop of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything)" to place the TextView where you want it.