# How to create Overlay layout in android

Tags: android

How can i create the layout like i attached in the background as normal any layout.From that  layout when i click any or get back to that layout, the overlay layout should come with any form fields buttons or text ...any

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You want to interchange the layouts visibility or what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: What i mean., in the layout bottom Airtel text.Ff i touch that, The number layout wants to up.Again clcik the same number layout need to down to hide. something like  android keybowrd display (if click textbox the android keybord will slide up same effect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android overlay a view ontop of everything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. The last child view will overlay everything else.

To be sure the overlay view is on top, you can call `ViewGroup.bringChildViewToFront()` on the relative layout.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_view">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

</FrameLayout>
```

In this layout, editText2 will cover the editText1

Comment: Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `FrameLayout`, you can add objects one in front of the other. Please read about it at documentation.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` can also be used for this.

Comment: yes, but I find it alot easier with frame layout, tho its not really hard with relative layout also

Comment: yes but click any buttons or any thing from the background (parent)layout to slide up the child layout something like animation down to up

Answer (score 0):

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!-- other actual layout stuff here  -->

       </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
    </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Now any view you add under LinearLayout with `android:id = "@+id/overlay"`
will appear as overlay with gravity = right

hopefully this will help you