# Website overlay content does not scroll when viewed on Android

Tags: android, css, overlay

Thanks for any help you can provide! I am trying to finish up a mobile version of my website, but for some reason, the content that appears in the overlay that I have created does not scroll properly when viewed on Android. This is not a problem on iPhone. I have viewed this link, but I don't think it applies: [Android overlay a view ontop of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything)

Here is a link to my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/kevindp78/TkQJa/3/
And a link to the full version if you want to see this in action on android: http://jsfiddle.net/kevindp78/TkQJa/3/embedded/result/

Here is the full HTML

```
<div id="webpagecontent"><ul>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
<li>This is my webpage content.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="fixedoverlay">
   <div id="overlaymatte"></div>
   <a title="close" href="#" class="closeoverlay">Close</a>
   <div id="overlaycontent"><ul>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
       <li>Here's all of my overlay content.</li>
   </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#fixedoverlay, #overlaymatte {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 999;
}
#overlaycontent {
position: relative;
max-width: 95%;
margin: 25px auto;
height: 50px;
overflow: auto;
background: #fff;
padding: 10px;
/*  border: 20px solid #fff; */
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 9999;
}

#fixedoverlay #loaderimg {
display: block;
margin: 50px auto;
}
#fixedoverlay .closeoverlay {
position: absolute;
display: block;
padding: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #666;
background: #eee; 
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
left: 50%;
top: 12px;
margin-left: 0px;
z-index: 999999999;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain Android browsers (If I am correct, version 2.x and below) do not support the CSS `overflow` property, thus any element within a page with a fixed height that needs to scroll, will not be scrollable in those older Android browsers (I believe this also does effect older versions of the iPhone, too).

You can try out [Overthrow JS](http://filamentgroup.github.io/Overthrow/). It has saved my bacon a few times with tasks such as what you describe, it is a Javascript plugin but it's worth it if you must use a scrollable element.

Implementation is very simple, just put the JS file in the `<head>` tag of your document and assign the class `overthrow` to the element you want to scroll using touch.

There may be better plugins out there for this, however overthrow is the only one I have used.

**NOTE** You will have to combine in with some sort of scrollbar plugin to display scrollbars, Overflow JS merely allows you to scroll the content on mobile browsers, for this I have used [ScrollPane JS](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) but I have never used both of these together, I can't see why it wouldn't work though.

### **NOTE#2**

After doing some more reading on this it appears [TinyScrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) will do what you want! It allows you to scroll on mobile browsers according to the Features section

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is the answer I'm looking for a long time!