# XML Drawable not expanded to View size, or View not inheriting its parent's height correctly, on Android API < 11

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-drawable

Consider the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!-- some views here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm using it to have `bg2` on top of `bg1` while `bg2` remains completely independent, such that I can apply e.g. a tween alpha animation to it without affecting anything else.

`bg1` and `bg2` are XML drawables. Obviously, they're supposed to be scaled to their respective View's dimensions. This is normally the case and it doesn't seem to make much sense to specify their dimensions explicitly.

Unfortunately, on Android versions prior to 3/API 11, it looks as if the size of `bg2` will be zero. Maybe the two-phase layout measurement is buggy (note how `bg2` is supposed to inherit its height from its parent, which in turn needs to adjust to the `LinearLayout`´s height and propagate that information to the View containing `bg2`). Or maybe the View won't accept its parent's height (although I tried `ImageView` which changed nothing).

The Layout you see is really used for items in a list.

The XML drawables are stateful and use gradients.

Can you think of an approach which would also work for Android API 8 to 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of testing (subclassing `View`, overriding `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()`) reveals that `FrameLayout` is broken in this respect in older Android versions.

Since `FrameLayout` fails to pass its own height down the hierarchy in this scenario (the `View` will always see `0` both with `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()`) there is no obvious way to work around this problem by subclassing.

The question then was, is there another way to overlay the two views which Android 2.2 aka API 8 can handle correctly.

And alas, there is. The same can be achieved with a `RelativeLayout`, which involves much more overhead of course, though the actual increase in rendering effort should be limited.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item"
        android:background="@drawable/bg2" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```