# ImageView match_parent different for Jelly Bean and Froyo

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.2-froyo

I have a simple layout and bumped into difference between Jelly Bean and Froyo. On Jelly Bean I have `ImageView` matched its parent (`FrameLayout`) by height. But on Froyo it is not. Please have a look on layout structure:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_data_background_im"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test text"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test text"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test text"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So what I have on Jelly Bean (and it is as expected):

[image]

Here is what I have on Froyo:

[image]

Please advice how to have the `ImageView` to fill its parent as it is for Jelly Bean. Thank you very much.

Comment: First, your screenshots are of the Eclipse preview, which is not especially relevant. Test using emulators or devices. Second, when you ran Hierarchy View to take a look at the size of your `ImageView`, what did you learn?

Comment: It's a bug; [see here, also for a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780884/1856738)

Comment: Mark, I've tested on real devices, I've just taken screen shots from IDE. I didn't check with Hierarchy View, I'll do so.

Comment: Why do you have the FrameLayout anyway? You already have a LinearLayout there...

Comment: @WarrenFaith This is just a part of more complex layout, I need it to be.

Comment: @WarrenFaith - this is a real problem: the ImageView don't get stretched by height of it's parent container on Froyo

Comment: Guys, it's a _bug_. I looked at the source code. Also, Silk's case is valid. Silk, I suggest the workaround from the link I already posted.

Comment: Class Stacker, thank you very much for workaround, it solves my problem. Please put your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this same phenomenon only recently. After looking at the Android source and subclassing View such as to see what values the `FrameLayout` would pass down to its children, it became obvious that this is a bug.

See here for a full flavoured [description](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15780884/1856738) and [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793790/1856738).

Meta note: Thank you, StackOverflow reviewers, for voting *for* converting my original answer into a comment and then *against* marking this question as a duplicate. Now that's what you get for it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `FragmentLayout`'s `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Your XML code should be as below

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: No, I need it to be "wrap_content" because this is just a part of more complex layout.

Comment: This would result in a stretched background for the complete screen.

Comment: The problem is I don't need it to be stretched for the complete screen but for a part.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put that `profile_data_background_im` `Drawable` as a background for your `@+id/ll` `LinearLayout`? Strange mix of layouts anyway.

Comment: Because I'm using more complex solution here, third party library to have an ImageView with rounded corners and tiled background.