# How Cover the whole screen by textview irrespective of other elements present in the XML file?

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout

How can i cover the screen by TextView i written Below but it does not work 
I want the Facebook buttons to show sometimes i dont want them to show i just want to show a

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either re-order your RelativeLayout to place the element you want on top at the bottom of the layout list, or use a FrameLayout.  A FrameLayout will allow you to overlay elements.

See here:
[Android overlay a view ontop of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is very simple. You are adding your `TextView` first and then you are adding `ImageView`. Both these are set to match parents width and height but since you are adding `ImageView` later its z-index is greater than that of `TextView`.

To confirm these just remove the ImageView and then check.

Hope this helps :)