# Hide View element with zero height and width in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have two ListView and I want them to share the same layout position so when I click a button one ListView hides.
Maybe this is not possible or there is a better way like fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FrameLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything). This layout view overlies two views over each other.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

For showing the first page (i.e. the first `ListView`):

```
findViewById(R.id.list1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.list2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And for the second page:

```
findViewById(R.id.list1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.list2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Perfekt! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

fragments are the easy way to do this IF you don't plan on changing the data in your views.

Make a button and

```
/*create fragment of the opposite view, probably through a boolean field and an if block
then*/
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(/*your fragments*/).commit().
```

in your onclicklistener.