# What is the name of the top and bottom bar as shown in the picture in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'd like to ask, what is the name of the top and bottom bar as shown in the figure below? Is it a notification bar or what? Thanks.

[image: Android App Image]

Comment: Those are custom widgets Waze created.

Comment: The first tab is an overlay, to work with it, try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519160/android-overlay-a-view-ontop-of-everything and the second one seems to be a custom designed frame with buttons and textviews. Try making it using various layouts and widgets available.

Comment: @SanVed Thank you so much, i got it. Basically, it just an overlay between layouts.

Comment: @AdamGardner Thanks for the reply.