# Creating snapchat like button for android app

Tags: android

Hi I'm creating a camera app and my first activity is similar to snapchat.

I've followed the android camera dev tutorial (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html).

But unfortunately it didn't cover a specific type of button that I want (snapchat like button).

I want to have buttons like snapchat.

Here's my current view xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="capture" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my mainactivity java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance(getApplicationContext());

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });

}
```

I believe the problem stem from after rendering the xml layout, the tutorial add

```
preview.addView(mPreview);
```

Over the layout which I believe the camera preview is drawn over the button.

I've only thought of two solution to this.

One is programmatically add a button after preview.addView(mPreview); line. Or if there's somekind of z-index that I can set on the xml code for the button?

And the snapchat button is an image button? I guess my overall question is how I can create buttons like snapchat app.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759036/how-to-send-view-to-back-how-to-control-the-z-order-programmatically) seems a reasonable solution to me

Comment: or you could use `ViewGroup.bringChildToFront();`

Answer (score 1):

Add `captureButton` programmatically to `FrameLayout` the same way that you added `mPreview` to the layout.

```
// Add mPreview to the layout first
// so we can build on top of it
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mPreview);

// Then captureButton will go on top of mPreview
Button captureButton = new Button(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT
);
captureButton.setLayoutParams(params);
preview.addView(captureButton);
```

The order of appearance is very important with a FrameLayout because you cannot set the z-index of views manually. The z-index is set automatically based on the order of appearance. The first view to be added to `FrameLayout` will be the bottom layer (`mPreview`). Consecutive layers will build on top of the view that came before it.

As for making the button semi-transparent, I recommend creating a drawable and doing something like

```
Drawable cameraButton = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawableName);
cameraButton.setAlpha(170);
captureButton.setBackground(cameraButton);
```