# Overlaping view in linearlayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Please help me how can i get this type of view in Linear Layout .
[image]

I have tried

```
   android:layout_gravity=""
   android:layout_weight=""
```

and after click i want that tag with full view like the 1s tag appearing in picture.

Comment: easy way relative layout. hard way custom layout.

Comment: i have  used but still the same layout i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks I have completed with the help of [Turix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759036/how-to-send-view-to-back-how-to-control-the-z-order-programmatically).

Describing shortly .First i have send all views on Backend on OnClick() of any button using this code

```
    public static void sendViewToBack(final View child) {
    final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)child.getParent();
    if (null != parent) {
        parent.removeView(child);
        parent.addView(child, 0);
    }
}
```

and then used

```
            curentView.bringToFront();
```